# How to implement touch listener on image?

Tags: android

I am developing an application. In my application I am display images using `ImageView` from url using xml parsing. I want to display zoom image when I double touch on the Image, then again double touch on zoomImage, I want to reset image. How to implement in image using Android?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is how you implement a touch listener in Android.

```
        yourImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                return false;
            }
       });
```

To detect double taps you use GestureDetector like this:

1) Make your own GestureDetector, derived from SimpleOnGestureListener and override the methods you're interested in (see google's docs on SimpleOnGestureListener for the exact methods you can override, I've done double tap here):

```
class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
{

@Override
 public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e)
 {
    Log.i("Taghere..", "onDoubleTapEvent");
    return true;
    }
}
```

2) Create an instance of your gesture detector. I'm making a member variable and instantiating in onCreate.

```
    private GestureDetector mDetector;

    mDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());
```

3) Setup a touch listener on your imageview and route the messages to your gesture detector:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourimageviewid);
iv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}});
```

I would override the methods in MyGestureDetector and log to logcat like I'm doing on double tap to get a feel for how this works.

Comment: @rreeverb,I want to determine "User touch double or single touch on image",How i do?

Comment: Hmm, I really don't know for sure, sorry. You might look into GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.  If all else fails you can get the time the touch occurred and compare it with the time of the last touch and see if it falls within the time of 'double tap.'

Comment: GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener actually

Comment: Yeah give me a minute and I will.

Comment: @ok Thanks rreeverb,i am waiting for your answers.

Comment: OK there you go, I edited the answer to include an example. I tried out double tap and it seems to work as expected. Pretty cool functionality.

Comment: @ok Thanks,i have one new idea,i have  5 images,i want to display that images in GestureDetector one by one and left to right and right to left,

Answer (score 0):

***Touch listener for imageview***

**

```
**ImageView imageview=findViewById(R.id.iamgeview);
imageview.setOnTouchListener(new Multi**TouchListener2());
```

**

```
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MultiTouchListener2 implements OnTouchListener,OnGestureListener {

    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
     boolean isRotateEnabled = true;
     boolean isTranslateEnabled = true;
     boolean isScaleEnabled = true;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    private float mPrevX;
    private float mPrevY;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleGestureDetector;
    private GestureDetector gd;
    static View v;
    ImageView tv;

    public MultiTouchListener2() {

        mScaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(new ScaleGestureListener());
        gd = new GestureDetector(this);
        gd.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener() {
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                return false;
            }
            public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                return false;
            }
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });




    }
    public MultiTouchListener2(ImageView dummy) {
        mScaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(new ScaleGestureListener());
        tv=dummy;
        gd = new GestureDetector(this);

        gd.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener() {
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

                return true;
            }
        });


    }

    private static float adjustAngle(float degrees) {
        if (degrees > 180.0f) {
            degrees -= 360.0f;
        } else if (degrees < -180.0f) {
            degrees += 360.0f;
        }

        return degrees;
    }

    private static void move(View view, TransformInfo info)
    {
        v=view;
        computeRenderOffset(view, info.pivotX, info.pivotY);
        adjustTranslation(view, info.deltaX, info.deltaY);
        float scale = view.getScaleX() * info.deltaScale;
        scale = Math.max(info.minimumScale, Math.min(info.maximumScale, scale));
        view.setScaleX(scale);
        view.setScaleY(scale);

        float rotation = adjustAngle(view.getRotation() + info.deltaAngle);
        view.setRotation(rotation);
    }

    private static void adjustTranslation(View view, float deltaX, float deltaY)
    {
        float[] deltaVector = {deltaX, deltaY};
        view.getMatrix().mapVectors(deltaVector);
        view.setTranslationX(view.getTranslationX() + deltaVector[0]);
        view.setTranslationY(view.getTranslationY() + deltaVector[1]);
    }

    private static void computeRenderOffset(View view, float pivotX, float pivotY) {
        if (view.getPivotX() == pivotX && view.getPivotY() == pivotY) {
            return;
        }

        float[] prevPoint = {0.0f, 0.0f};
        view.getMatrix().mapPoints(prevPoint);

        view.setPivotX(pivotX);
        view.setPivotY(pivotY);

        float[] currPoint = {0.0f, 0.0f};
        view.getMatrix().mapPoints(currPoint);

        float offsetX = currPoint[0] - prevPoint[0];
        float offsetY = currPoint[1] - prevPoint[1];

        view.setTranslationX(view.getTranslationX() - offsetX);
        view.setTranslationY(view.getTranslationY() - offsetY);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        v=view;
        boolean result = mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(view, event);
        boolean isScaling = result = mScaleGestureDetector.isInProgress();

        if (!isScaling)
        {
            result = gd.onTouchEvent(event);
        }




        if (!isTranslateEnabled) {
            return true;
        }

        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action & event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                if(tv!=null)
                    tv.setAlpha(150);
                mPrevX = event.getX();
                mPrevY = event.getY();
                mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                if (pointerIndex != -1) {
                    float currX = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                    float currY = event.getY(pointerIndex);

                    if (!mScaleGestureDetector.isInProgress()) {
                        adjustTranslation(view, currX - mPrevX, currY - mPrevY);
                    }
                }

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if(tv!=null)
                    tv.setAlpha(255);
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mPrevX = event.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mPrevY = event.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        return result ? result : mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(view, event);
    }

    private class ScaleGestureListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
    {
        private float mPivotX;
        private float mPivotY;
        private Vector2D mPrevSpanVector = new Vector2D();

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(View view, ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            v=view;
            mPivotX = detector.getFocusX();
            mPivotY = detector.getFocusY();
            mPrevSpanVector.set(detector.getCurrentSpanVector());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(View view, ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            v=view;
            TransformInfo info = new TransformInfo();
            info.deltaScale = isScaleEnabled ? detector.getScaleFactor() : 1.0f;
            info.deltaAngle = isRotateEnabled ? Vector2D.getAngle(mPrevSpanVector, detector.getCurrentSpanVector()) : 0.0f;
            info.deltaX = isTranslateEnabled ? detector.getFocusX() - mPivotX : 0.0f;
            info.deltaY = isTranslateEnabled ? detector.getFocusY() - mPivotY : 0.0f;
            info.pivotX = mPivotX;
            info.pivotY = mPivotY;
            info.minimumScale = 0.1f;
            info.maximumScale = 10.0f;

            move(view, info);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private class TransformInfo {

         float deltaX;
         float deltaY;
         float deltaScale;
         float deltaAngle;
         float pivotX;
         float pivotY;
         float minimumScale;
         float maximumScale;
    }
}





public class ScaleGestureDetector {
    private static final String TAG = "ScaleGestureDetector";


    public interface OnScaleGestureListener {

        public boolean onScale(View view, ScaleGestureDetector detector);


        public boolean onScaleBegin(View view, ScaleGestureDetector detector);


        public void onScaleEnd(View view, ScaleGestureDetector detector);
    }


    public static class SimpleOnScaleGestureListener implements OnScaleGestureListener {

        public boolean onScale(View view, ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onScaleBegin(View view, ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            return true;
        }

        public void onScaleEnd(View view, ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            // Intentionally empty
        }
    }


    private static final float PRESSURE_THRESHOLD = 0.67f;

    private final OnScaleGestureListener mListener;
    private boolean mGestureInProgress;

    private MotionEvent mPrevEvent;
    private MotionEvent mCurrEvent;

    private Vector2D mCurrSpanVector;
    private float mFocusX;
    private float mFocusY;
    private float mPrevFingerDiffX;
    private float mPrevFingerDiffY;
    private float mCurrFingerDiffX;
    private float mCurrFingerDiffY;
    private float mCurrLen;
    private float mPrevLen;
    private float mScaleFactor;
    private float mCurrPressure;
    private float mPrevPressure;
    private long mTimeDelta;

    private boolean mInvalidGesture;

    private int mActiveId0;
    private int mActiveId1;
    private boolean mActive0MostRecent;

    public ScaleGestureDetector(OnScaleGestureListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mCurrSpanVector = new Vector2D();
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getActionMasked();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            reset(); // Start fresh
        }

        boolean handled = true;
        if (mInvalidGesture) {
            handled = false;
        } else if (!mGestureInProgress) {
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    mActiveId0 = event.getPointerId(0);
                    mActive0MostRecent = true;
                }
                break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    reset();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
                    // We have a new multi-finger gesture
                    if (mPrevEvent != null) mPrevEvent.recycle();
                    mPrevEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
                    mTimeDelta = 0;

                    int index1 = event.getActionIndex();
                    int index0 = event.findPointerIndex(mActiveId0);
                    mActiveId1 = event.getPointerId(index1);
                    if (index0 < 0 || index0 == index1) {
                        // Probably someone sending us a broken event stream.
                        index0 = findNewActiveIndex(event, mActiveId1, -1);
                        mActiveId0 = event.getPointerId(index0);
                    }
                    mActive0MostRecent = false;

                    setContext(view, event);

                    mGestureInProgress = mListener.onScaleBegin(view, this);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
                    mListener.onScaleEnd(view, this);
                    final int oldActive0 = mActiveId0;
                    final int oldActive1 = mActiveId1;
                    reset();

                    mPrevEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
                    mActiveId0 = mActive0MostRecent ? oldActive0 : oldActive1;
                    mActiveId1 = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());
                    mActive0MostRecent = false;

                    int index0 = event.findPointerIndex(mActiveId0);
                    if (index0 < 0 || mActiveId0 == mActiveId1) {
                        index0 = findNewActiveIndex(event, mActiveId1, -1);
                        mActiveId0 = event.getPointerId(index0);
                    }

                    setContext(view, event);

                    mGestureInProgress = mListener.onScaleBegin(view, this);
                }
                break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                    final int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
                    final int actionIndex = event.getActionIndex();
                    final int actionId = event.getPointerId(actionIndex);

                    boolean gestureEnded = false;
                    if (pointerCount > 2) {
                        if (actionId == mActiveId0) {
                            final int newIndex = findNewActiveIndex(event, mActiveId1, actionIndex);
                            if (newIndex >= 0) {
                                mListener.onScaleEnd(view, this);
                                mActiveId0 = event.getPointerId(newIndex);
                                mActive0MostRecent = true;
                                mPrevEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
                                setContext(view, event);
                                mGestureInProgress = mListener.onScaleBegin(view, this);
                            } else {
                                gestureEnded = true;
                            }
                        } else if (actionId == mActiveId1) {
                            final int newIndex = findNewActiveIndex(event, mActiveId0, actionIndex);
                            if (newIndex >= 0) {
                                mListener.onScaleEnd(view, this);
                                mActiveId1 = event.getPointerId(newIndex);
                                mActive0MostRecent = false;
                                mPrevEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
                                setContext(view, event);
                                mGestureInProgress = mListener.onScaleBegin(view, this);
                            } else {
                                gestureEnded = true;
                            }
                        }
                        mPrevEvent.recycle();
                        mPrevEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
                        setContext(view, event);
                    } else {
                        gestureEnded = true;
                    }

                    if (gestureEnded) {
                        setContext(view, event);

                        final int activeId = actionId == mActiveId0 ? mActiveId1 : mActiveId0;
                        final int index = event.findPointerIndex(activeId);
                        mFocusX = event.getX(index);
                        mFocusY = event.getY(index);

                        mListener.onScaleEnd(view, this);
                        reset();
                        mActiveId0 = activeId;
                        mActive0MostRecent = true;
                    }
                }
                break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    mListener.onScaleEnd(view, this);
                    reset();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    reset();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    setContext(view, event);

                    if (mCurrPressure / mPrevPressure > PRESSURE_THRESHOLD) {
                        final boolean updatePrevious = mListener.onScale(view, this);

                        if (updatePrevious) {
                            mPrevEvent.recycle();
                            mPrevEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return handled;
    }

    private int findNewActiveIndex(MotionEvent ev, int otherActiveId, int removedPointerIndex) {
        final int pointerCount = ev.getPointerCount();

        final int otherActiveIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(otherActiveId);

        for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++) {
            if (i != removedPointerIndex && i != otherActiveIndex) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private void setContext(View view, MotionEvent curr)
    {
        if (mCurrEvent != null)
        {
            mCurrEvent.recycle();
        }

        mCurrEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(curr);

        mCurrLen = -1;
        mPrevLen = -1;
        mScaleFactor = -1;
        mCurrSpanVector.set(0.0f, 0.0f);

        final MotionEvent prev = mPrevEvent;

        final int prevIndex0 = prev.findPointerIndex(mActiveId0);
        final int prevIndex1 = prev.findPointerIndex(mActiveId1);
        final int currIndex0 = curr.findPointerIndex(mActiveId0);
        final int currIndex1 = curr.findPointerIndex(mActiveId1);

        if (prevIndex0 < 0 || prevIndex1 < 0 || currIndex0 < 0 || currIndex1 < 0) {
            mInvalidGesture = true;
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid MotionEvent stream detected.", new Throwable());
            if (mGestureInProgress) {
                mListener.onScaleEnd(view, this);
            }
            return;
        }

        final float px0 = prev.getX(prevIndex0);
        final float py0 = prev.getY(prevIndex0);
        final float px1 = prev.getX(prevIndex1);
        final float py1 = prev.getY(prevIndex1);
        final float cx0 = curr.getX(currIndex0);
        final float cy0 = curr.getY(currIndex0);
        final float cx1 = curr.getX(currIndex1);
        final float cy1 = curr.getY(currIndex1);

        final float pvx = px1 - px0;
        final float pvy = py1 - py0;
        final float cvx = cx1 - cx0;
        final float cvy = cy1 - cy0;

        mCurrSpanVector.set(cvx, cvy);

        mPrevFingerDiffX = pvx;
        mPrevFingerDiffY = pvy;
        mCurrFingerDiffX = cvx;
        mCurrFingerDiffY = cvy;

        mFocusX = cx0 + cvx * 0.5f;
        mFocusY = cy0 + cvy * 0.5f;
        mTimeDelta = curr.getEventTime() - prev.getEventTime();
        mCurrPressure = curr.getPressure(currIndex0) + curr.getPressure(currIndex1);
        mPrevPressure = prev.getPressure(prevIndex0) + prev.getPressure(prevIndex1);
    }

    private void reset() {
        if (mPrevEvent != null) {
            mPrevEvent.recycle();
            mPrevEvent = null;
        }
        if (mCurrEvent != null) {
            mCurrEvent.recycle();
            mCurrEvent = null;
        }
        mGestureInProgress = false;
        mActiveId0 = -1;
        mActiveId1 = -1;
        mInvalidGesture = false;
    }


    public boolean isInProgress() {
        return mGestureInProgress;
    }


    public float getFocusX() {
        return mFocusX;
    }


    public float getFocusY() {
        return mFocusY;
    }

    public float getCurrentSpan() {
        if (mCurrLen == -1) {
            final float cvx = mCurrFingerDiffX;
            final float cvy = mCurrFingerDiffY;
            mCurrLen = (float) Math.sqrt(cvx * cvx + cvy * cvy);
        }
        return mCurrLen;
    }

    public Vector2D getCurrentSpanVector() {
        return mCurrSpanVector;
    }

    public float getCurrentSpanX() {
        return mCurrFingerDiffX;
    }

    public float getCurrentSpanY() {
        return mCurrFingerDiffY;
    }


    public float getPreviousSpan() {
        if (mPrevLen == -1) {
            final float pvx = mPrevFingerDiffX;
            final float pvy = mPrevFingerDiffY;
            mPrevLen = (float) Math.sqrt(pvx * pvx + pvy * pvy);
        }
        return mPrevLen;
    }


    public float getPreviousSpanX() {
        return mPrevFingerDiffX;
    }


    public float getPreviousSpanY() {
        return mPrevFingerDiffY;
    }


    public float getScaleFactor() {
        if (mScaleFactor == -1) {
            mScaleFactor = getCurrentSpan() / getPreviousSpan();
        }
        return mScaleFactor;
    }


    public long getTimeDelta() {
        return mTimeDelta;
    }

    public long getEventTime() {
        return mCurrEvent.getEventTime();
    }
}







public class Vector2D extends PointF {

    public Vector2D() {
        super();
    }

    public Vector2D(float x, float y) {
        super(x, y);
    }

    public static float getAngle(Vector2D vector1, Vector2D vector2) {
        vector1.normalize();
        vector2.normalize();
        double degrees = (180.0 / Math.PI) * (Math.atan2(vector2.y, vector2.x) - Math.atan2(vector1.y, vector1.x));
        return (float) degrees;
    }

    public void normalize() {
        float length = (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        x /= length;
        y /= length;
    }
}
```