# How to detect only a particular gesture in SimpleOnGestureListener?

Tags: android, gesture

I want to change activity only on a particular gesture on a particular view.

For example 
on Activity A -

1. double tap on View 1 should change current Activity to B
2. swipe on View 2 should change current Activity to C

Answer (score 0):

In the OnTouchListener, you can pass the view that triggered the event:

```
      public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event){... this.onClick(v); ...}
```

just call the functions (IE: onClick) and then check if the view is the one you need to trigger this event:

```
      public void onClick(View v){
          switch (v.getId()){
              case R.id.X: {DO THIS}
              case R.id.Y: {DO THAT}
```

Comment: Have u seen an example for this?

Comment: I mean can I see that example somewhere online :)

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896173/androidview-and-ontouchlistener

Comment: I guess my question wasn't so clear. Its like in sequence
1) detect which gesture 
2) detect which view
3) see from a table the combination of (Gesture, View , Next Activity)
and open that activity.

Comment: it doesn't matter. The listeners trigger some functions when a touch event is fired. All you need to do is know how was this event fired (from which view) and act accordingly (if the gesture is a swipe and comes from the view x, do this. if the gesture is a doubleclick and comes from the view Y do that. that way, you create only 1 touch listener and use it from all your views, filtering the activities that should start next.

Comment: Those are too many questions to answer. There are many touch listener sample codes available in the web, including this same question and answer site. search for one, implement the view filtering like i've shown you, and you'll be on your way to the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still trying to figure out because I've not worked with gestures before. And right now for e.g. if I swipe too many gestures are called too many times.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following Listners

```
1) GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener

2) OnGesturePerformedListener
```

One for Double Tab and Second listner for Swipe, as you will get unimplemented methods call your activity from there.

Comment: Have u seen an example for this?

Comment: I have done work on GestureDetector.onDoubleTapListner, and it works fine, just pass intent on it method.