# how to test touch events on emulator

Tags: android, touch-event

I have some code to check onTouchEvent on an ImageView

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Log.d("M", "down");
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            Log.d("M", "moved");
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

But I am unable to test this on emulator. Can someone help me out

Comment: silly question maybe, but you can't use the mouse?

Comment: I also got really confused then I replaced Log with Toast message and suddenly I could see mouse click working !! but still action move is not firing , any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Touch events should be emulated already (no pun intended) with the mouse.
Try setting your listener like this:

```
 yourImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                return false;
            }
       });
```

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207067/how-to-implement-touch-listener-on-image) previous question.

Comment: actually I am overriding onTouchEvent method from View class

Comment: Your method is `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)`.  The one I suggested is `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e`).  They're two different methods, and I've never seen the first one used, so I figured it might be worth a try.

Comment: In fact, I just tried my method on the emulator, and everything worked fine.