# how to create this text header shape in android

Tags: android, shapes

i design my app in photoshop and i create most of my design but i cant create this shape:
[image: shape for header]

but i only can create rectangle with code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:width="80dp" android:height="30dp" />
    <solid 
        android:color="@color/blue"/>

</shape>
```

anyone can help me?
thanks for yr reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you absolutely need it to be an android shape? Or could you simply use a png?

Check this out on how to make a custom button: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

Or for the most flexibility add an imageview: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

And then set an ontouch listener to it:
[How to implement touch listener on image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207067/how-to-implement-touch-listener-on-image)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i cant create .9.png  file for this image can you help me

Comment: Have you tried going with the imageview option. You don't need it to be a .9.png file. It can just be a png. If you do go with this option make sure to make several versions of the picture for different screen resolutions.http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/